# How to Update a column Before Select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am setting a stored procedure for select and I want to update the value of one column in the database Before doing the Select.

This is what I tried but it's not working.

`@roleID int` and `@query varchar(240)`

```
SELECT 
    EP.Equipe_Projet_Id AS PROJET_ID,
    U.USR_ID, 
    CleRepartition = CASE
                        WHEN @RoleID = 1 AND @query IS NOT NULL 
                           THEN 100  
                                AND (UPDATE EQUIPE_PROJET SET CleRepartition = 100 
                                     WHERE EP.Equipe_Projet_Id = @PROJET_ID AND EP.Role_Id = 3)
                           ELSE NULL      
                      END   
FROM 
    [EQUIPE_PROJET] EP
```

Expecting update of column on database and having it's value

Comment: what is the problem ? Do you get an error ? What does `but it's not working` means ?

Comment: There's no `UPDATE` clause in the above? To update the value of a column, you need to use `UPDATE`.

Comment: The problem that's giving me error in the update. I thin that the syntax is not correct.

Comment: `SELECT CleRepartition= ..` does not update anything. It's another syntax for alias `SELECT .. AS   CleRepartition`.

Comment: *"The problem that's giving me error in the update"* Great, but what's the error? We can't see what you see, and we can't run your SQL. When guiding the blind, you need to give them clearly instructions, not vague details.

Comment: @Larnu I don't know how to update in my querry while Select. The idea is to update the value of CleRepartition in the database with the result of cases. And select the new value. CleRepartition is having now 0 as value and i want it to be 100-@requete for case 1 and 20 for case 2. I hope it's clear.

Comment: Is this a subsection of your code? Where are &#64;roleId and &#64;requete declared?

Comment: *"I don't know how to update in my querry while Select"*  `UPDATE MT SET MyColumn = YT.OtherColumn FROM MyTable MT JOIN YourTable YT ON MT.ID = YT,fID;` it's all in the documentation: [UPDATE (Transact-SQL) - Examples: Specifying a table alias as the target object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#l-specifying-a-table-alias-as-the-target-object).

Comment: @SEarle1986 i updated the question. It's more simple now. I am setting a stored procedure to do this.

Comment: @Larnu when i do this it's underlined red on  "CASE WHEN XX THEN YY AND UPDATE   " ? The problem is to do then and update

Comment: `UPDATE` is a reserved keyword, @kOe. If you have a column called `UPDATE` you need to delimit identify it (`[UPDATE]`). Personally would avoid using reserved keywords as obejct names. Also, why do you have an `AND` in your `THEN`? YOur boolean logic goes in your `WHEN` not your `THEN`.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to do an `UPDATE` inside a `SELECT` statement? You can't do that. You can use a `SELECT` statement within an `UPDATE` statement, but you can't do a `UPDATE` as a subquery within a `SELECT`. I think you need to take a step back, and expalin what your *real* goal is here.

Comment: @Larnu Exacttly i am trying to do an UPDATE inside Select. I am new in sql and don't know how to do in another way

Comment: You can't, @kOe. That isn't how SQL works.

Comment: you've updated the question but you still have a variable with no declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored procedure can do update then select after.

So I added the query of update in the beginning, then I do the select.

Like this:

```
UPDATE EP 
SET CleRepartition = CASE
                        WHEN @RoleID = 1 AND @query IS NOT NULL 
                           THEN 100  
                           AND (UPDATE EQUIPE_PROJET 
                                SET CleRepartition = 100 
                                WHERE EP.Equipe_Projet_Id = @PROJET_ID 
                                  AND EP.Role_Id = 3)
                           ELSE NULL      
                     END    
FROM [EQUIPE_PROJET] EP

SELECT 
    EP.Equipe_Projet_Id AS PROJET_ID,
    U.USR_ID, 
    CleRepartition  
FROM 
    [EQUIPE_PROJET] EP
```

I hope that this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to update the value of Column `CleRepartition` in the database while selecting.

This is not possible in a `SELECT` query.  A `SELECT` retrieves data from the database.  An `UPDATE` modifies data.  These are two separate statements and cannot be combined.

You are doing this work in a stored procedure.  Within a stored procedure, you can run an `UPDATE` and `SELECT` in any order, so you can accomplish both tasks.  If you are concerned about data changing in the database between the two statements, you can wrap them in a transaction.